# correct conversion fom Vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

hi guys i have a problem with this code

```
if(cbFilterOnColor.Checked == true)
        {
            imgGrayColorFiltered == imgSmoothed.InRange(new Bgr(dblMinBlue, dblMinGreen, dblMinRed), new Bgr(dblMaxBlue, dblMaxGreen, dblMaxRed));
        }
```

I have an error which tells me this : "only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

what can i do with this...

dblMax and dblMin are filled comboboxes with numbers from 0 to 255. And imgGrayColorFiltered is type of `Image<Bgr, Byte>`

PS: i wanted to transform this from VB to c#

```
imgGrayColorFiltered = imgSmoothed.InRange(New Bgr(dblMinBlue, dblMinGreen, dblMinRed), New Bgr(dblMaxBlue, dblMaxGreen, dblMaxRed))
```

Comment: In C# assignment uses a single `=`, comparison double `==`.

Comment: 1) `if(something == true)` can be replaced by `if(something)`. 2) replace `imgGrayColorFiltered == ...` with `imgGrayColorFiltered = ...` as you want to assign a vanue (=) and compare (==).

Comment: I think you did not specify what your actual problem is. The second section is already in C# format. And as Dirk mentioned, '=' is for assignment and '==' is for comparison.

Comment: imgGrayColorFiltered == imgSmoothed.InRange(new Bgr(dblMinBlue, dblMinGreen, dblMinRed), new Bgr(dblMaxBlue, dblMaxGreen, dblMaxRed))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a variable use a single =.

```
if (cbFilterOnColor.Checked)
{
    imgGrayColorFiltered = imgSmoothed.InRange(new Bgr(dblMinBlue, dblMinGreen, dblMinRed), new Bgr(dblMaxBlue, dblMaxGreen, dblMaxRed));
}
```